# Which are the different ways to deploy clojure web apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku, deployment, clojure, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There is a lot of infomation scattered throughout the internet regarding this issue.

Can anyone give me an overview about clojure web app deployment? The differences between deployment in a standalone server vs a containerless aproach? The advantages and disadvantages among the different players such as Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk (EB), Heroku, Google App Engine, etc? Support for maven and lein?

Thanks!